# Change level(s) of totals with GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, group-by, query

I am interested in the totals and the details of every line, in other words, the results of the second query.

Is there an easier way to do a rollup, and just have grandtotals?
(my 'live' query has more group levels that his example...)

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (a int, b int, c int)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,1,1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,1,2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,1,3)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,2,1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,2,2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,2,3)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,3,1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,3,2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,3,3)

SELECT a,b,c, COUNT(*)
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY ROLLUP(a,b,c)

-- 2nd query
SELECT a,b,c, COUNT(*)
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY ROLLUP(a,b, c)
HAVING (c is not null and b is not null) or a is null
```

Comment: Can you change the subject so that it describes the functional problem you’re trying to solve?

Comment: change title from "Can this be done simpler?"  to  "Change level(s) of totals with GROUP BY (in MS-SQL"

Answer (score 2):

(You don't say which DBMS, but inferring SQL Server from your temporary table name..)

If you're on a recent enough version (>=2008 ?) you can achieve the fine level of rollup control you're after with GROUPING SETS. For your 2nd query, the equivalent would be:

```
SELECT a,b,c, COUNT(*)
FROM #TEMP
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((a,b,c),())
```

Comment: That did the trick!